# string.format() with at least one decimal place

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

From the following two - double precision - numbers:

```
123456
0.0003232
```

I need to get (at least one decimal place) ...

```
123456.0   (one decimal place added)
0.0003232  (same as above)
```

... and never scientific notation, like E+000. The more close result from standard `string.Format()` is `string.Format("{0:F1}", myDoubleVal)` but in the second case the decimals are lost.

What else can I try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the below

```
string.Format("{0:0.0###########}",myval);
```

Thanks